# Cannot install NuGet Package

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with an mvc web application that uses OutputCacheAttribute. But at mobile caching I have problem. This problem has been solved at [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/09/17/asp-net-mvc-4-mobile-caching-bug-fixed.aspx).

Now I cannot install [Fixed DisplayModes](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes). It gives the following error:

```
Install-Package : Dış paketler projeleri hedefleyen paketlere bağımlı olamaz.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Also, I don't want to upgrate to mvc5 and I'm using vs2010 with mvc4.

How to overcome this problem?

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to target a version compatible with Asp.Net MVC4

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes -Version 1.0.1